# Can the HTML 5 <template> tag be used without the 'repeat' attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I have seen examples of using the HTML 5 `template` tag with a `repeat` attribute to perform two-way data binding (similar to AngularJS):

```
<template repeat="{{items}}">
    <a href="{{link}}">
        <img src="{{image}}" />
    </a>
</template>
```

With associated JavaScript model:

```
template.model = {
    items: [ {
        link: '...'
        image: '...'
    } ]
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/falafelsoftware/8fa8g

It doesn't seem like `repeat` should be a requirement for this behaviour, but as soon as I remove it:

```
<template>
    <a href="{{link}}">
        <img src="{{image}}" />
    </a>
</template>
```

And adjust the model accordingly:

```
template.model = {
    link: '...'
    image: '...'
```

I can't get anything to render: http://jsfiddle.net/8fa8g/9/

Can `template` be used without `repeat`?

Comment: Interesting. Because according to [mdn's write-up on `<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template), it's supposed to be like meta-data (in that it's never presented). Though in your example it's used like a `<div>`. I would venture to guess this is a poor example/implementation.

Comment: I have no idea how this is even working. According to [this](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/template.html) and [this](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding.html#templates-with-data-binding), `repeat` and the `{{}}` syntax are Polymer-specific features, and you're not even loading Polymer (just the platform polyfills)! [Here's](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/#toc-using) how `template`s are supposed to be used sans-Polymer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer (as I found following CletusW's link) seems to be the `bind` attribute:

```
<template bind="{{item}}">
    <a href="{{link}}">
        <img src="{{image}}" />
    </a>
</template>
```

This still requires an annoying level of indirection in the model:

```
template.model = {
    item: {
        link: '...'
        image: '...'
    }
```

But appears to work in both FF and Chrome.

However, as CletusW further points outs, it's not clear what specification this is defined in?